# Increase radius of html link

Tags: html, css

How can I increase the radius of a link without increasing the size of its content or changing the size of its parent?

I have some links with small images attached, it works fine but it is hard to click exactly on the image (especially on mobile). I'm trying to modify the link so that even if you click nearby it (lets say +-10px) it will still go the the desired url.

my Html:

```
<i class="icon-plus-sign" onclick="javascript:ClickMe();" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
```

My guess is, that I should make a css class and apply it to the link, but I have no idea how to make css

`padding:10px` will change my page design by increasing the size of the link's parent.

Comment: Can you please post your html code?

Comment: would something like `.padding-sm { padding: 10px; }` work?

Comment: You're on the right track with css. You could just enclose the link and image in a `<div></div>` and assign a class with a defined margin or padding size. Then assign an onClick event handler to the DIV that does the same as the link.

Comment: padding both padding and div size will change the size of the parent and will ruin the page design

Comment: I know what you are saying about increasing the div size changing the layout, but you can't have two over-lapping 'hot' areas - how would you know which has been clicked? Therefore the padding is the spacing between the displayed elements that are clickable. Or am I missing something? Can you post more of the HTML showing how the links are arranged together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to expand the clickable area, you can use `padding:10px`. However if you want the bounding size not to change, just try applying `margin:-10px` :

```
i {
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px;
  margin:-10px;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/25x74/)

In the demo, you can see the border of the parent `div` is close to the inner `i` child as if there is no change in size of the `i`. However hovering mouse over the area around the `i` element can still affect the cursor to change to `pointer`, that's when you can click your icon.

Comment: Like that trick a lot, but it here's a modified version of that demo that demonstrates the overlap problem I mention in the comments to the OP. Just try to click link 1. - http://jsfiddle.net/bTYbr/

Comment: @FatMonk thanks for the feedback on the issue, I think the OP should not use it in such a case, however we can have a quick fix by setting all the `padding-bottom:0` and `margin-bottom:0` on the above `i` and `padding-top:0` and `margin-top:0` on the below `i` like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/bTYbr/1/

Comment: @King King Yup.. Good fix, that'll do it. In css there's always a way - the job is to find it.

Answer (score 1):

you can increase its sizing area by giving her

```
padding:10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/3K6Qq/

just use the

```
style="padding:10px;"
```

and vary the number of pixels to change the size of your link and you don't need a separate css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div under the image and make it whatever size you want.

I used this and it works perfectly

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="#">
        <div id="expand">
        </div>
 </a>
```

I like the padding idea better though.